# fast ajax update

Tags: jquery, post

I'm trying to replicate some functionality which looks similar with the process of adding comments on SO. I’m using jQuery AJAX post: $.post(), but the process of adding a comment take longer on my machine than on SO.

I assume that SO uses a much smarter approach. Do you know how SO does comments add/edit?

Comment: The `stackoverflow` tag is actually for `stackoverflow`... Not for this site `;-)` Regarding your question, well we can't answer it without knowing what the heck are you doing in your code...

Comment: @gdoron: You're right about the tag. sorry. When I do $.post() I send the data to a php file which does the insert. On success the same data is added as a <div> to the page.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough to answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine is almost certainly *far* inferior to stackoverflow servers! Look in your web dev tools for a request made by stackoverflow and compare it to one you make. You'll find they are likely very similar.